# Angular ui-grid firefox issue with using minimized/obfuscated files

Tags: angularjs, firefox, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

When using angular ui-grid in firefox with minimized/obfuscated files with following additional directives: gid-cell-navi and grid-cell-edit only in file fox I experience strange bug [image: see image]

when I type first character I get binary image display not sure why, word that I've typed was 'test'

Comment: I've the same issue. The first key you press when editing starts adds an UTF invisible character that is shown as in your image.

Comment: Would be nice to find out what this all about.